# Code Signing error on adding Watch App - Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, code-signing-certificate

I’m getting the below error when I added watch app with extension to my app. I’m not able to build and run the app even in simulator. I have tried lot of options provide in many articles. But none works for me.

Can anyone help me on this issue. Thanks

```
ValidateEmbeddedBinary /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleApp-dasjqaqfdsifddln/Build/Products/QA-watchsimulator/SampleAppWatch.app/PlugIns/SampleAppWatchExtension.appex (in target: SampleAppWatch)
    cd /Users/***/Workspace/SampleApp
    builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleApp-dasjqaqfdsifddln/Build/Products/QA-watchsimulator/SampleAppWatch.app/PlugIns/SampleAppWatchExtension.appex -signing-cert - -info-plist-path /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SampleApp-dasjqaqfdsifddln/Build/Products/QA-watchsimulator/SampleAppWatch.app/Info.plist

error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

        Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    Not Code Signed
        Parent App Signing Certificate:     - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)
```

Please find the Target settings of my app below

**App target**

```
identifier - com.company.sampleApp
```

**Watch app target**

```
 identifier - com.company.sampleApp.sampleAppwatch

 info.plist

    WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier - com.company.sampleApp
```

**Watch extension app target**

```
identifier - com.company.sampleApp.sampleAppwatch.watchkitextension

info.plist

    WKAppBundleIdentifier - com.company.sampleApp.sampleAppwatch
```

Automatic Code Signing and selected same team for all targets

**Key Chain access**

```
Trust Certificate is 'Use System Defaults'
```

Enabled app groups for App, Watch app and Watch extension

**Using Xcode 10.3**

Comment: I have the same problem, have you finally solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need open scheme of your app and change it build configuration to debug.

Comment: Mapk - QA is one of the debug target in our application. Only environment will get change based on QA or debug.

Comment: As you could read in error message, you trying to build your app with adhoc provision profile in your SampleAppWatch target, and empty provision in your SampleAppWatchExtension target.
Also you can't run adhoc build on simulator or device using xcode.
Adhoc build is king of release build designated to distribution using installation via itunes on devices that included in adhoc provision profile instead of releasing it to appstore/testflight.

Comment: you could try to open each of your targets uncheck/check automatic code sign, but i think you trying to do something wrong. If you wan't to install run app throug xcode on simulator/device, you need select debug build configuration in your target scheme. Adhoc build designated to distribution via archive->adhoc->copy yourappname.ipa->install it on device using itunes or airdrop.